# Gstreamer : proper way to release resources of a pipeline?

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I'm building a pipeline in Gstreamer, using a UriDecodeBin. This pipeline is meant to be build and released repeatedly, but I have a hard time to figure out how to properly delete the pipeline.

For now, I'm trying to figure out what to unref and what not to unref to get all resources of a pipeline to be released, with just a UriDecodeBin in the pipeline, but I can't get the full memory to be released somehow.

My sequence of actions is as follows :

Fist, I'm building the pipeline and UriDecodeBin :

```cpp
_pipeline = (GstPipeline*)gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");
_bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(_pipeline); //will be manually observed
_decoder = gst_element_factory_make("uridecodebin", "decoder");
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(_pipeline), _decoder);
gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(_decoder);
std::string uri = std::string("file://some_video_file");
g_object_set(_decoder, "uri", uri.c_str(), nullptr);

g_signal_connect(_decoder, "no-more-pads", G_CALLBACK(GsDecoder::no_more_pads_cb), (gpointer)this);
changePipelineState(GST_STATE_PAUSED);
```

Then, I wait for the no-more-pads to trigger, and add a blocking probe on each pad :

```cpp
GstIterator *it = gst_element_iterate_src_pads(_decoder);
GValue padV = G_VALUE_INIT;
while(gst_iterator_next(it, &padV) == GST_ITERATOR_OK){
  GstPad* pad = (GstPad*)g_value_get_object(&padV);
  GstCaps* caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);
  if(caps_is_audio(caps)){
    _decoderAudioSrcs.push_back(pad); //adding pad to a collection
    gulong id = gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, GsDecoder::pad_blocked_cb, (gpointer)this, NULL); //blocking probe
    _decoderAudioProbeIds.push_back(id); //remembering id of the probe, for later
  } else if (caps_is_video(caps)){
             //same with video but file is guaranteed to have a single video track.
    _decoderVideoSrc = pad; 
    _decoderVideoProbeId = gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, GsDecoder::pad_blocked_cb, (gpointer)this, NULL);
  } else {
            std::cout << "UNKNOWN PAD FOUND" << std::endl;
  }
  gst_caps_unref(caps); //releasing caps
  g_value_unset(&padV);
}
```

At this point I wait that all probes block the pads, and then I unblock the pads :

```cpp
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _decoderAudioSrcs.size(); i++){
  gst_pad_remove_probe(_decoderAudioSrcs[i], _decoderAudioProbeIds[i]);
}
gst_pad_remove_probe(_decoderVideoSrc, _decoderVideoProbeId);
play(); //setting the pipeline to play
```

Finally, after a bit of time, I order the pipeline to delete itself, and there I am a bit confused about what shall be deleted or not (both in this pipeline and in general).

- How shall the pipeline be deleted ? From what I understood, I have to set pipeline state to Null, and then unref everything (pads, decoder, bus, pipeline) using `g_object_unref`, however it still leads to pipeline having few refs pointing to it (in my case, 3), and not releasing its resources, would it be memory nor threads.
- Is there a way to tell Gstreamer to fully delete a pipeline and everthing related to it, without having to unref everything by hand ?

Especially, I would be interested in a pointer to some documentation, since I couldn't found any on the subject (even if Gstreamer doc mentions unrefing time to time).

Answer (score 0):

GStreamer objects are reference counted. Whenever the reference drops to 0 the object gets deleted. The GStreamer documentation usually tells you for a function about its transfer behavior. E.g.

`gst_pad_get_current_caps()`
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstpad.html#gst_pad_get_current_caps

Tells you the transfer is full and you are supposed to release it when you make no more use it (you do so in your sample code). If you don't do it, it will never be deleted.

So the typical use case is if-i-don't-need-it-anymore-i-release-it. That does not mean that it gets deleted. For example, if you put an element into a pipeline, the pipeline will add a reference to it. It will take care of the reference and release it once the pipeline's reference count drops to 0. But since you added it to the pipeline and your code itself does not need it anymore you would usually just release it.

So you need to the careful about the references. If you miss one tiny small object which may be part of a big pipeline it may result in many objects to not be released as they depend on each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was looking for a more complete doc than the (mentioned in my question) specific documentation of the each function, like one recapitulating overall deletion process of a pipeline. Turns out I partially solved the problem (I forgot to unref bus messages after popping them), but some memory leaks remain in my setup, which is only composed of a decodebin u_U. Do you know if there is a way to force Gstreamer to release all resources of a pipeline without caring about ref counting ?